# Connecting to windows remote share in PHP

Tags: php, windows, apache, network-programming, easyphp

I am trying to connect to a directory shared in my network (something like \remoteserver\mydir) with php.
I tried the function fopen but it tells me that I don't have the permission to connect, so it seems that the function reaches the server but can't access the directory, which was understandable since the function doesn't get credentials in input.
I tried also to make the remote directory as network unit (Z:) but the function still doesn't get through. Currently I have two environment where i can test this one is using EasyPhp and the other one is using WAMP.

Does anybody of you have ever get this done?

Thanks in advance
Best

Answer (score 0):

Here is someone who explains some of it:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php#90373

```
// Define the parameters for the shell command
$location = "\\servername\sharename";
$user = "USERNAME";    
$pass = "PASSWORD";
$letter = "Z";

// Map the drive
system("net use ".$letter.": \"".$location."\" ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:no>nul 2>&1");

// Open the directory
$dir = opendir($letter.":/an/example/path")
```

Comment: Sadly nothing, it does not work.
This thing is really driving me crazy.